# Select a range of rows based of off total row height

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

A little background, I have a vbs code that pulls from multiple excel files and then pastes them into word documents to create reports. Everything works like it should, however I am needing to be able to select a range of rows based off of their combined row height. The reason for this is because I am copying a graph and pasting it into word as a picture, the code then opens an other excel file and selects the data and pastes it into word as a picture below that graph and then continues on a loop until it has went through all the files. I can fit 8 normal sized rows (14.3) or a total row height of 114.4 below the graph, if the used range of rows have a combined row height greater than this then it needs to go to the next page.

What I have now is the code will look at the used range and if it is greater than 8 rows it will select the used range and paste it onto the next page or if the used range is less than 8 it will select a total of 8 rows even if they are empty and paste it to keep it looking uniform throughout the report. However there are times when there are less than 8 rows worth of data but a row or two had to be increased to fit all the text (column widths have to be fixed as there is a set area it has to fit into on the word document) therefor making the total row height of the 8 rows greater than 114.4 and it will no longer fit below the graph. In this case I need it to select based off of a combined row height of 114.4 and not just 8 rows.

I hope I have explained what I am needing to do well enough for some much needed help. Below is my current attempt on trying to select data based off of row height... It will run through the code without errors, however it will just go off of the used range, I can not get the code referring to row height to do anything, it is if it just ignores that code.

```
Sub Events(f)
    Set objWkb3 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
    LastRowEvents = objWkb3.Sheets("Events").usedRange.Rows.Count
    LastRowEvents1 = objWkb3.Sheets("Events").usedRange.Rows
    LastRowEvents2 = objWkb3.sheets("Events").usedRange.RowHeight
    LastRowEvents3 = objWkb3.sheets("Events").Range("F1:F8").RowHeight


    'Selection of Events
    If LastRowEvents > 8 then
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph
    Elseif LastRowEvents2 > 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph
    Elseif LastRowEvents2 = 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    Else objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F8").CopyPicture
    End If

    'Events to PJR
    wsh.sleep 1500
    objWord1.Selection.Paste
    objWord1.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph

    'Events to Gas
    objWord2.Selection.Paste
    objWord2.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph

    'objWkb3.Save
    objWkb3.Close(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: How isn't it working? Do you get an error? Is there unexpected behavior? Also could you kindly edit your first paragraph so it's not just a wall of text, it's kind of hard to follow.  Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the original post better explaining why it was not working. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around and trying different things, by changing the .RowHeight to .Height I was able to get the code work how I was wanting.

```
Sub Events(f)
    Set objWkb3 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
    LastRowEvents = objWkb3.Sheets("Events").usedRange.Rows.Count
    LastRowEvents1 = objWkb3.Sheets("Events").usedRange.Rows
    LastRowEvents2 = objWkb3.sheets("Events").usedRange.Height
    LastRowEvents3 = objWkb3.sheets("Events").Range("A1:F8").Height
    MRow1 = Round(((114.4 - LastRowEvents2)/14.3),0)
    MRowT = MRow1 + LastRowEvents

    'Selection of Events
    If LastRowEvents > 8 then
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph
    Elseif LastRowEvents2 > 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph
    Elseif LastRowEvents2 = 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    Elseif LastRowEvents3 > 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & MRowT).CopyPicture
    Elseif LastRowEvents3 = 114.4 then 
    objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F" & LastRowEvents).CopyPicture
    Else objWkb3.Sheets("Events").Range("A1:F8").CopyPicture
    End If

    'Events to PJR
    wsh.sleep 500
    objWord1.Selection.Paste
    objWord1.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord1.Selection.TypeParagraph

    'Events to Gas
    objWord2.Selection.Paste
    objWord2.Selection.MoveRight
    objWord2.Selection.TypeParagraph

    'objWkb3.Save
    objWkb3.Close(0)
End Sub
```